# What does the word "Trident" in my user agent string refer to?

Tags: internet-explorer, user-agent

According to the UserAgentString.com website, my user agent string is Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Does this mean that I'm using Internet Explorer 11 with an Internet Explorer 7 user agent? UserAgentString.com states that "Trident" is the layout engine for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It means that the version of IE is 11 and the version of Trident is 7.

For each IE version since at least IE 8, the Trident version has been the `IE version - 4`. So IE 8 had Trident/4.0.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if the Trident version was in some way tied to the IE version. For example Trident/7.0 = IE 7.0. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 25):

Actually what @libertyernie said was that IE8 is Trident 4 and going on:

- IE 8 = Trident/4.0
- IE 9 = Trident/5.0
- IE 10 = Trident/6.0
- IE 11 = Trident/7.0